# See an extern variable from a webmethode

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services

I have an ASP.Net application with c#.
I have this code :

C#:

```
public string a="abc"; 

[WebMethode]
public static Boolean check(string delegate)
{
   .....

   return true;

  }
```

This method I call from javascript.Can somebody tell me how can i use "a" variable from webmethode ?

Comment: This won't compile. `WebMethode` is not an attribute and `delegate` is a reserved keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either declare the variable as static (make it a [class variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691162%28v=vs.71%29) as opposed to an [instance variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691164%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)):

```
public static string a = "abc";
```

Or create an instance of the class inside the method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Boolean check(string @delegate)
{
    MyClass cls = new MyClass();
    var a = cls.a;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing instance member in a static method, you will have to create an instance of the current class. Then you can access it.

Like if The class is `Class1`

then your method will

```
[WebMethode]
public static Boolean check(string str)
{

   var obj = new Class1();
   // Now you can access a variable like obj.a
   .....

   return true;

}
```